# Using ParametricNDSolveValue with initial conditions as parameters

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

Recently I've came across the command `ParametricNDSolveValue`, which allows the user to solve DEs with one or more parameters. I've tried setting

```
Y := ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1, y[x0] == y0}, 
  y, {x, -10, 10}, {x0, y0}]
```

and then plugging in $x_0=y_0=0$, and evaluating at $x=1$ using `Y[0, 0][1]`. However, the result of the latter doesn't go through as expected at all. I'm getting an output of the form

```
ParametricFunction[ <> ][0, 0][1]
```

instead of the number $1$ (or some approximation of it).

I noticed that setting $x_0$ as an external parameter to `ParametricNDSolveValue`, that is defining

```
Clear[Y]
Y[x0_] := 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1, y[x0] == y0}, y, {x, -10, 10}, 
  y0]
```

and following up with `Y[0][0][1]` does indeed give $1.0$ as expected.

My questions are: is there really no way to use `ParametricNDSolveValue` with one of the parameters being the point at which the initial condition is given? If so, is my solution considered elegant? Is there a better way to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: @MMM nope, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `NDSolve` instead?

```
sol[x0_, y0_] := NDSolve[{y'[x] == 1, y[x0] == y0}, y, {x, -10, 10}];
yfun = First[y /. sol[0, 0]];
yfun[1]
```

> 1