# Make the initial condition of a differential equation a function. DSolve and ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I'm trying to  do something with DSolve and  after  I want to translate the solution of the problem to  "ParametricNDSolve", however I can't.

This is the problem, I have a function, and a differential equation that depends on this function

```
f[c_] := c+c^2;
DE = DSolve[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[f[c]] == 1}, r[x], x];
```

With this code I get

```
r[x] -> (1 + x)^4/(1 + c+c^2)^4
```

So if a choose a particular $c$, I get a particular initial condition, for example $c=1$, then

```
r[x] -> (1 + x)^4/(3)^4
```

Now, if I choose for example $x=0$,  I get  $r[0]=1/3^4$. However I have to do this "manually", I can't find a way to do with code.

I try with  ParametricNDSolve, for example

```
DEP = ParametricNDSolve[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[ f[c]   ] == 0},r, {x, 0, 100}, {c}];
```

With $f$ defined as before. And after of this I try to evaluate the solution in a specific initial condition and in some specific point, for example $c=1$ and $x=0$ 
using

```
r[1][0]/.DEP
```

However this does not work, I know that ParametricNDSolve needs to have a predefined value of $f[c]$ in order to work, but I can't find a way fix this value.

I need to solve the problem with  ParametricNDSolve because the differential equation that I'm working seems that doesn't have analytical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I found the answer combining a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137072/using-parametricndsolvevalue-with-initial-conditions-as-parameters)   with my problem.

To solve the problem I will use NDSolve. We take $fg(c)$ as a function of $c$.

```
fg[c_] := c + c^2;
```

Now we can define the differential equation

```
DEE[c_] := NDSolve[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[fg[c]] == 1}, r, {x, -10, 10}];
```

And then we define another function

```
 yfun = First[r /. DEE[1]];
```

And this mean that I choose $c$ to be $c=1$.

Then you can evaluate in $x=0$

```
yfun[0]
```

Such that  $yfun[0]=0.0123456$ and this value is equal to $1/3^4$, so the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen this before. I do not think the Parameter, in `ParametricNDSolve` can be in the initial condition/Boundary condition but only in the ODE itself. That is why it does not work. You get the same exact error as if you did `NDSolve[{D[r[x]/(1+x)^4,x]==0,r[f[c]]==1},r,{x,0,100}]` with `c` not defined.

If you look at the examples in [ParametricNDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) all have the parameter inside the ODE, not in the initial conditions.

One away around this, is to use `NDSolve` but manually vary `c` each time you solve the ODE. Like this

[image]

```
ClearAll[f, c];
f[c_?NumericQ] := c + c^2;
Manipulate[

 Module[{x, sol, r},
  sol = NDSolve[{D[r[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, r[f[c]] == 1}, r, {x, 0, 100}];
  Plot[Evaluate[r[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 100},
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 300}},
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLabel -> "Solution for the ODE",
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "r[x]"}, BaseStyle -> 12]
  ],

 {{c, 1, "c"}, 1, 5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c}
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the reading of another post.